# Dynamic generated sitemap -there are only declared pages on sitemap

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo

I'd like to generate dynamic url fo each slug, but there is an array only with pages which I declared: `const pages = ["/", "/about", "/portfolio", "/blog"];`
`http://localhost:3000/api/my-sitemap`. I've installed npm sitemap from https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap

my query in ../../lib/data.js

```
export const getBlogSlugs = async () => {
  const endpoint =
    "https://api-eu-central-gsagasgasxasasxsaxasxassaster";

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint);

  const query = gql`
    {
      posts {
        slug
      }
    }
  `;
  return await graphQLClient.request(query);
};
```

pages/api/my-sitemap.js

```
import { getBlogSlugs } from "../../lib/data";
const { SitemapStream, streamToPromise } = require("sitemap");
const { Readable } = require("stream");

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const { posts } = await getBlogSlugs();
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
};

export default async (req, res, posts) => {
  try {
    const links = [];
    posts?.map((slug) => {
      links.push({
        url: `/blog/${slug}`,
        changefreq: "daily",
        priority: 0.9,
      });
    });

    // Add other pages
    const pages = ["/", "/about", "/portfolio", "/blog"];
    pages.map((url) => {
      links.push({
        url,
        changefreq: "daily",
        priority: 0.9,
      });
    });

    // Create a stream to write to
    const stream = new SitemapStream({
      hostname: `https://${req.headers.host}`,
    });

    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "application/xml",
    });

    const xmlString = await streamToPromise(
      Readable.from(links).pipe(stream)
    ).then((data) => data.toString());

    res.end(xmlString);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
};
```

I added to my robots.txt in pudblic folder:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://localhost:3000/api/my-sitemap
```

What I got is only declared pages

[localhost:3000/api/my-sitemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu3db.png)

I tried like this and doesn't work too:

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const data = await getBlogSlugs();
  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.posts,
    },
  };
};

export default async (req, res, posts) => {
  try {
    const links = [];
    posts?.map((post) => {
      links.push({
        url: `/blog/${post.slug}`,
        changefreq: "daily",
        priority: 0.9,
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use getStaticProps from an API route.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16068#discussioncomment-703870

You can fetch the data directly inside the API function.

Edit: In my app, I use the API route code below to fetch data from external server

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await fetch("YOUR_URL");
    const posts = await result.json();
//use posts
    });
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

For GraphQl may be you can check the example given in vercel site
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-graphql

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean ;/

Comment: I'm looking how to do it and so far I can't find the example how to fetch data inside the api function.

Comment: I have edited the answer, what I meant was you cannot use getStaticProps inside the internal nextjs  API route , the logic you use in getStaticProps can be implemented directly in API Routes function

Comment: Kinda I need to learn more about API Routes, because I dont know how to implement that, lol. Anyway Thank for your replies.